# Move .out log file from default location to custom location in weblogic 12c?

Tags: server, weblogic12c, system-administration

I want to move `*.out` **log** file of Node manager to my own custom location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing following arguments on Weblogic console, I was able to change the default location of `*.out` **nodemanager log** file.

```
-Dweblogic.Stderr=/usr/local/Weblogic12c/logs/error/servererror.out
```

---

Add the options `-Dweblogic.Stdout=<outfile>` and  `-Dweblogic.Stderr=<errorfile>` In order to move all **logs** to a **separate location.**

Comment: Official documentation about these parameters can be found in
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24487/weblogicserver.htm#CCHCAEDI

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing the location of the file, you can also redirect more of the output to the standard .log file defined for the server.

Something similar to the command line options `-Dweblogic.Stdout=<outfile> and  -Dweblogic.Stderr=<errorfile>` is to login to the weblogic console and do the following for each server:

```
Servers -> <server name> -> Logging Tab advanced section -> 
Check both "Redirect stdout logging enabled" and "Redirect stderr logging enabled"
```

Unfortunately this does not help with the fact that the .out files will grow in size without being rotated. See [this link](https://community.oracle.com/message/10170409?#10168409) for some info on how you can rotate the .out files yourself.